# How to call a known method of a generic object

Tags: c#, reflection

*Sorry couldn't find a relevant SO question.*

I use Reflection to get a property (which is another object) of an `object` using:

```
public static T GetPropertyValue<T>(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    return (T)prop.GetValue(obj, null);
}
```

I have a (Xero) Api that looks like:

```
public class XeroCoreApi : XeroApi
{
    public AccountsEndpoint Accounts { get; }
    public ContactsEndpoint Contacts { get; }
    // ...
}
```

Where the `Endpoint`s inherit a class that looks like:

```
public abstract class XeroUpdateEndpoint
{
    public TResult Update(TResult item);
    // ...
}
```

i.e. I can call updates on the specific entities:

```
Contacts.Update(...);
```

When I do call the `GetPropertyValue()` method I get the `Endpoint` object from an instance of the `XeroCoreApi` but I don't know it's *methods* (really I do, but the compiler doesn't) until run-time.

To obtain the `Endpoint` I run the command similar to:

```
var endpoint = _api.GetPropertyValue<object>("Contacts");
// For the sake of this example the "Contacts" is manually
// entered, violating the whole idea of generics
```

The problem is I can't do something like `endpoint.Update(...)` (since the `endpoint` is a `var` and *some* `endpoint` don't particularly inherit the *Update()* method).

Is it possible to run the method using Reflection? What might the syntax look like?

**Summary:**

How to call a method (`Update()`) of an object of type `T` (i.e. we don't know the object until run-time) using reflection?

E.g. `endpoint.Update(...)`

Comment: Your question is pretty confusing. What do you mean by "some endpoint don't particularly inherit the Update() method"? What *do* you know at compile-time when you're trying to call the method? It would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* example of what you're trying to achieve. While you certainly can use reflection (`typeof(T).GetMethod(...).Invoke(...)`) or dynamic typing, it sounds like you shouldn't need to here.

Comment: Right there! `endpoint.GetType().GetMethod("Update", ...).Invoke(endpoint, args);` was exactly what I was looking for - just wasn't aware of the syntax. Thanks Jon [appreciate that you provided a sample syntax without fully knowing the question :)]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/d5x73970.aspx) (not reflection). This gives the compiler the proof that your type satisfies some conditions.

For example, an interface:

```
public interface IUpdateStuff {
    void Update();
}

public class XeroCoreApi : XeroApi, IUpdateStuff {
    // implementation here
}
```

Then you can constrain your generic type:

```
public TResult Update(TResult item) where TResult : IUpdateStuff ;
```

Now the compiler will let you:

```
public TResult Update(TResult item) where TResult : IUpdateStuff {
    item.Update(); // <-- this is okay now.
}
```

EDIT: This assumes your generic type comes from the enclosing class.. which it appears to in your example.